# When i undo migration sequelize delete my table or rename to table_backup

Tags: javascript, node.js, migration, sequelize.js

I have some tables, one of them is called `events` table. When i run migration everything looks ok, but if I undo last migration my undo-migration ends without any error. When I check my db, my table has been renamed to `event_backup`, so when i try do migration i have error because table `event` has been renamed to `event_backup` and table `event` does not exist.

Last migration file:

```
module.exports = {
  up: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    return queryInterface
      .addColumn('temp', 'StudyId', {
        type: Sequelize.UUID,
        references: {
          model: 'studies',
          key: 'id',
        },
        onUpdate: 'CASCADE',
        onDelete: 'SET NULL',
      })
      .then(() => {
        return queryInterface.addColumn('temp', 'SubjectId', {
          type: Sequelize.UUID,
          references: {
            model: 'subjects',
            key: 'id',
          },
          onUpdate: 'CASCADE',
          onDelete: 'SET NULL',
        });
      })
      .then(() => {
        return queryInterface.addColumn('events', 'SubjectId', {
          type: Sequelize.UUID,
          references: {
            model: 'subjects',
            key: 'id',
          },
          onUpdate: 'CASCADE',
          onDelete: 'SET NULL',
        });
      })
      .then(() => {
        return queryInterface.addColumn('events', 'StudyId', {
          type: Sequelize.UUID,
          references: {
            model: 'studies',
            key: 'id',
          },
          onUpdate: 'CASCADE',
          onDelete: 'SET NULL',
        });
      });
  },

  down: queryInterface => {
    return queryInterface
      .removeColumn('temp', 'StudyId')
      .then(() => {
        queryInterface.removeColumn('temp', 'SubjectId');
      })
      .then(() => {
        queryInterface.removeColumn('events', 'SubjectId').then(() => {
          queryInterface.removeColumn('events', 'StudyId');
        });
      });
  },
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not returning the `Promise` inside `then` statement. `events` table is renamed temporarily to `events_backup` for the time of migration. When migration finishes you get `events` table back, but because `Promise` is not being returned you are stuck with incomplete migration.

To fix `undo` migration add `return` keyword before each `queryInterface.removeColumn`.

Now when you start `undo` migration your `events` table will be temporarily renamed to `events_backup` and then to `events` table back again.

**See working example.**

```
  down: queryInterface => {
    return queryInterface
      .removeColumn('temp', 'StudyId')
      .then(() => {
        return queryInterface.removeColumn('temp', 'SubjectId');
      })
      .then(() => {
        queryInterface.removeColumn('events', 'SubjectId').then(() => {
          return queryInterface.removeColumn('events', 'StudyId');
        });
      });
  },
```

For more information about sequelize migrations see the [docs](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/migrations.html) here or this [amazing blog post](https://medium.com/@andrewoons/how-to-define-sequelize-associations-using-migrations-de4333bf75a7).